# Help with rewrite rules for two post types

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I'm trying to setup two rewrite rules for two post types. Basically, the structure I want is this:

`site.com/app/course/xxxx/` => adds query_var *course*

`site.com/app/course/xxxx/theme/xxxx/` => adss query vars *course* and *theme*

I set up two `add_rewrite_rule`:

```
public function rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%course%', '([^&]+)' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%theme%', '([^&]+)' );    

    add_rewrite_rule("^app/course/([^/]+)/?",'index.php?page_id=3400&course=matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule('^app/course/([^/]+)/theme/([^/]+)/?','index.php?page_id=3400&course=$matches[1]&theme=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
```

If I add just the first rule, it works. If I only add the second rule, it works too. But, if I add both, only the first rule works. The second rule loads a valid page, but the *theme* var is not set.

Am I doing something wrong? Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rule is capturing all requests. If you add a `$` anchor at the end of the rules, they'll behave as expected (you could also just switch the order of the rules so the more specific one "wins").

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^app/course/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=3400&course=matches[1]', 
    'top'
);
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^app/course/([^/]+)/theme/([^/]+)/?$',
    'index.php?page_id=3400&course=$matches[1]&theme=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```

Check out [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer) for debugging rules.

Also note that `theme` is used by WordPress internally as a POST or GET var, I suggest changing that to something unique to prevent any potential conflict.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `$` to the end of the rule works! Switching the order works too, but I prefer that structure. Also, thanks for the Monkeyman plugin. It's been a while since it has been updated, but the plugin works perfectly!